# How can I use a state in a url to make a get using axios in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am using axios in react to get information from a django backend, I am getting the user data and I am storing it in a state in the component but I want to use one of the attributes in the user_data state in the url of another get to get more information from the backend, I do not know if I explained it correctly but here is the code :

```
state = {
    user_data: [],
    classes: []
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    const config = {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
          'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    };
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config)
      .then(
        res => {
          this.setState({
            user_data: res.data
          });
        }
      )     
    const myString = this.state.user_data.SectionNumber
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Classes/${myString}`, config)
      .then(
        res => {
          this.setState({
            classes: res.data
            });
            console.log(res.data);
         }
      ) 
  }
```

I do not know how to change the state object into something that axios can understand and use in the url

Comment: is there any error that you are facing ?

Comment: You should pass the second call to fetch the class details as a callback to the first setState.

Answer (score 1):

At this point when you are fetching the user related data you do not need to depend on the state. You can pass the second call as a callback to the first setState so that it can update it when the promise resolves and state has been updated.

```js
axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config)
    .then(
        res => {
            this.setState({
                user_data: res.data
            });
        }, () => {
            const myString = this.state.user_data.SectionNumber
            axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Classes/${myString}`, config)
                .then(
                    res => {
                        this.setState({
                            classes: res.data
                        });
                        console.log(res.data);
                    }
                )
        }
    )
```

Comment: It worked but not exactly as you said, I am going to put the code as an answer if anyone in the future needs it

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the state and then take from the state to use this parameter in your url. You can use promises and pseudo-synchronous code async/await and it should help.

```js
 async componentDidMount() {
  const config = {
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('access')}`,
        'Accept': 'application/json'
     }
  };
  const userDataResponse = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config)
  const myString = userDataResponse.data.SectionNumber;
  const classesResponse = await axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Classes/${myString}`, config)
  this.setState({
     user_data: userDataResponse.data,
     classes: classesResponse.data
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked with me

```
axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/users/me/`, config)
      .then(
        res => {
          this.setState({
            user_data: res.data
          });
          const SectionNumber = this.state.user_data.SectionNumber
          axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/Elearning/Classes/${SectionNumber}`, config)
            .then(
              res => {
                this.setState({
                  classes: res.data
                });
              }
            )
        } 
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a similar problem and i have done exactly as you have shown but I do not see the results.

```js
 axiosInstance.get('/user/profile/' + this.state.adminCard).then(response => {
                    axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + response.data.access;  
                    this.setState({
                        fullName: response.data.lastName + ", " +  response.data.firstName,
                        diploma:  response.data.diploma,
                        projectSlug:  response.data.project
                    })
                }, () => {
                    const slug = this.state.projectSlug;
                    axiosInstance.get('/user/project/' + slug).then(response => {
                        axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + response.data.access;  
                        this.setState({
                            assignedProjectName: response.data.projectName,
                            assignedProjectDesc: response.data.projectDesc,
                            assignedProjectSupervisor: response.data.projectSupervisor
                        })
                        console.log(this.state.assignedProjectName)
                    })
                })
```

On the line where I console.log(this.state.assignedProjectName), I do not even get a return, please advice.